# Cannot read local file when using jnlp

Tags: java, file-permissions, jnlp

My application is throwing an java.security.AccessControlException when trying to access a file, localy on my machine.
While running the application from intellij, the file can be read, no problem.
When the app is deployed, so when starting the app via the jnlp, when trying to read the file, I get the AccessControlException.
(i.e. java.security.AccessControlException access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "C:\Users\jeff.g\Z_StartMenu_Win10.mp4" "read") )
I think the code will not bring any useful information, but here is a simplified version:

```
@Override
public void loadVideoFromFileSystem(String path, Video video, Runnable mediaLoadedListener) {
    CompletableFuture<Video> receiver = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(loadFromFileSystem(video, path));
    if (mediaLoadedListener != null) {
        receiver.thenRun(mediaLoadedListener);
    }
}

private Supplier<Video> loadVideoFromFileSystem(Video video, String pathToLoad ) {
    Supplier<Video> supplier = () -> {
        if (pathToLoad != null) {
            try {
                if (Files.isReadable(Paths.get(pathToLoad))) {
                    video.setContent(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(pathToLoad)));
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                LOG.error("...");
            }
            catch (SecurityException e){
                LOG.error("...");
            }
        }
        return video;
    };
    return supplier;
}
```

and it fails on the

```
Files.isReadable(Paths.get(pathToLoad))
```

The jnlp contains

```
<security>
   <all-permissions/>
</security>
```

and I've added a line into the java.policy file (just to test), in the grant section, with the full path to my file
e.g.

```
grant {
    permission java.io.FilePermission "C:\\Users\\jeff.g\\Z_StartMenu_Win10.mp4", "read,write";
}
```

I also tried with "\" and "/" , but this was for testing purpose only, the java.policy file should not be modified to have it working.

By the way, I've verified the certificate used to sign the jar, it is valid, and the certificate is installed on my machine and the clients machine, it fails everywhere.

Should you have any clue...

Many thanks.

**Edit:**

It looks like a sandboxing problem.
I've checked my jar, all my libraries are correctly signed.
I've also modified the javaws.policy file to grant access to the files, but nothing helps.

```
grant {
    permission java.security.AllPermission;
    permission java.io.FilePermission "<<ALL FILES>>", "read"; 
};
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) See [Detection/fix for the hanging close bracket of a code block](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251795/155831) for a problem I could no longer be bothered fixing. 3) ***Why*** is the app. trying to read a local file that will not be accessible once deployed?

Comment: Andrew, I've edited my description. The app allows users to upload videos from their worksations,  Videos are persisted and made available for others. this is the part where the user chooses the video

Comment: The edit includes no MCVE. Be sure to check the JNLP using JaNeLA, available at my [share drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/#folders/0B5B9wDXIGw9lUnJaUjA2cmlVRE0).

Comment: there was no significant error in the jnlp. This looks like a sandboxing issue. -> I've updated the main description at the end

Comment: Policy files are pointless for a properly signed JWS app, that is launched with all permissions. Where is the MCVE?